# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm having an issue showing the error on the start of the app after build

> "TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function"

As I found many similar question but my problem is different as I've reviewed my code 3 times, not got any import problem, before installing a library named `react-native-gifted-chat`, my app was working fine. But after that app started to show this error although I've just imported the library (Not Used Any Code of it).

[image]

But when I simply remove this line of code `import {GiftedChat} from 'react-native-gifted-chat';`, my app was working fine again.
Any suggestions?

My packages are:

```
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.13.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
"react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
"react-navigation": "4.3.3",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.11"
```

Answer (score 0):

[visit this page, this is the pull request for the issue.](https://github.com/expo/react-native-action-sheet/pull/162/commits/37156dacf114aa5146da153db9ee00c1aea8eaca)

Comment: Appreciated your answer but this doesn't seem to be helpful as I'm using React Hooks (Functional Approach), not classes. And this error is just because of this `import {GiftedChat} from 'react-native-gifted-chat'` line. When I remove this line, app works fine.

Comment: @AunAbbas I am having the same issue - how did you solve it?

Comment: @gwalshington I was facing a `multidex` error that is caused when you use many libraries in the project and the limit exceeds 64K methods. If you are also facing the same issue, you need to either set the `minSdkVersion` to 21 or follow the instructions from the given links:

https://rnfirebase.io/enabling-multidex#enabling-multidex

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle